# Windows shell context menu command to pass file name

Tags: c#, windows, shell, contextmenu

I'm using a shell context menu command to pass the filename to a very basic console app.

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\MyApp\command\"C:\myapp.exe" "%1"`

The problem is with executable files in downloads folder, Windows runs SmartScreen the same as if I was executing the file.
How can I send the filename from a context menu without executing the file and causing SmartScreen to run? I just need the filename.

**MyApp.exe**

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Filename: " + args[0].ToString());
    Console.Read();
}
```

So running the following command in cmd prompt doesn't cause SmartScreen to run but from the context menu it does:

```
C:\> myapp.exe c:\users\user1\downloads\test.exe
```

I thought this command in cmd prompt is equivalent to the registry context menu command?

Comment: So the EXE in the downloads folder is the parameter you want to pass to `myapp.exe` (not myapp.exe itself)?

Comment: Can you show us which techniques from Googling `c# context menu windows explorer` that you have already tried?

Comment: @mjwills Yes, I want to run myapp.exe and pass a filename of exe in downloads. It works, but it firsts shows SmartScreen. I added the registery context menu manually, so not sure about what techniques you are talking about?

Comment: Is there a way to right click on a file and pass it's filename to my app without actually executing the file or smartscreen?